# Trigger a password behavior on and off in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a textbox that I'm using as a password box, and I want to have the default password visible, and then when it is changed, hide it with `'*'`. So when the user opens the form, the Password text box will already have "welcome1" in the text box, but when they change it, the password will appear as "*******".

What I have at the moment:

```
if (txtPassword.Text == "welcome1")
{
    // Set txtPassword.PasswordChar to null or empty.
}
else { txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*'; }
```

Comment: The title doesn't correspond to the content. Do you need to reset the field of trigger password behaviour on and off?

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks @ivan_pozdeev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset the password character to not mask, set it to the null character:

```
txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

Default value specified on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is what I needed. I have added it to my code and now it does what I wanted :)

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, just figured it out:

```
private void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtPassword.Text != "welcome1")
    {
        txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: thats a bit silly in case someone wants to set the password to "welcome1" think about it again ;-)

Comment: I have other measures elsewhere in the program to combat this, but I guess in a more general sense yes, this is an unfinished solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use 2 text boxes. 1e Visible true 2e Visible false
And set the 2e text box Password Char to *
With a mouse click event on the first text box.
When somebody clicks the text box to type a password the text box changes.

```
    private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
```

Also put a form mouse click for if thy didn't type a text , go back to text box 1
or something like that.

```
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox1.Text = "Welcome1";
        }
    }
```